# Multiline Listview with icon

Tags: qt

Learning QT desktop development and interested in adding a List View like the below to my project.

The below is by way of example, I'm mainly after an icon with heading and multiline line text.

[image: sample look]

Are there any existing widgets or does anyone know where I can find information on extending the widget to extend the functionality?

Comment: Check [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27777-Customize-QListWidgetItem-how-to), there might be what you want.

Comment: I think you should look into qml rather than widgets...

Comment: I wrote [this element](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/games/gluon/repository/revisions/master/entry/player/fremantle/Button.qml) two years ago and a half in QML for Fremantle which would be a demonstration how much easier it would be to create such things in QML.

Comment: QML does look interesting, will take a closer look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy, just overload this function. If you want to learn how to use Qt, it is a good start to implement your own functionality into an interactive ItemDelegate and ListViewer! E.g. you also may add something like an PopUp if mouse is hovering over the icon.

```
void QAbstractItemDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index)
```

Another approach is it to use QML. You can chose what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that will point me in the right direction. Will try it in QML as well....not sure the QML C++ integration will work well once things scale up but there's one way to find out.